# Subset dataframe and put items in new column in R

Tags: r

My question is twofold. I want to filter a column in data frame df, based on different values. My column consists of many different car types. If I’m looking for a BMW 3er reihe for instance, I also want to include BMW 3er reihe; 3161 SEDAN.

```
Example dataset:

Item   Brand   Type
1      BMW     3er Reihe
2      BMW     3er Reihe; 3161 SEDAN
3      Audi    A1 
4      Audi    A3
```

I did this with grep:

```
carsegmentC <- df[grep("3er Reihe|A3", df$Type), ]
```

This works well and filters the data frame exactly how I want it to be filtered, but this presents more difficulties for the next part of my question. Ultimately I want to put the filtered outputs into a new column and back into the data frame. So it will look like this:

```
Item Brand  Type                      Carsegment C             Carsegment B
1   BWM     3er Reihe                 3er Reihe 
2   BMW     3er reihe; 3161 SEDAN     3er reihe; 3161 SEDAN
3   Audi    A1                                                  A1 
4   Audi    A3                        A3
```

This does not seem to work with grep and I’ve tried other things like copying columns, but it doesn’t work. Hopefully anyone can help, I’d appreciate it!

Reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(Item = c(1,2,3,4), Brand=c("BMW", "BMW", "Audi", "Audi"), Type=c("3er Reihe", "3er Reihe;3161 SEDAN ", "A1", "A3"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the patterns in a `list`, loop through the patterns, apply `grepl` to get a logical index, wrap it with `ifelse` to return `""` for the FALSE values in `grepl` and assign it to new columns in 'df'.

```
df[c("CarsegmentC", "CarsegmentB")] <- lapply(list("3er Reihe|A3", "A1"), 
       function(pat) ifelse(grepl(pat, df$Type), df$Type, ""))

df
#  Item Brand                 Type          CarsegmentC CarsegmentB
#1    1   BMW            3er Reihe            3er Reihe            
#2    2   BMW 3er Reihe;3161 SEDAN 3er Reihe;3161 SEDAN            
#3    3  Audi                   A1                               A1
#4    4  Audi                   A3                   A3
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Item = c(1,2,3,4), Brand=c("BMW", "BMW", "Audi", 
     "Audi"), Type=c("3er Reihe", "3er Reihe;3161 SEDAN", "A1", "A3"), 
     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```